# Load site specific config as well as application web.config

Tags: asp.net, iis-8

I have a asp.net mvc application which comes with web.config. I deploy it to my Windows server 2012 with IIS 8.

I have to make some changes to the web.config because of the unique settings on the server, for instance, disable a URL rewrite rule, to name a few.

I treat my application as a open source project which shouldn't include settings specific to my server. But if I don't put the unique settings in web.config, every time I deploy the site, I have to manually edit it again.

Are there ways to resolve the problem? Is it possible for IIS to load two web.config, one from the repository, the other somewhere on the server?

I know `<appsetting>` has `file` attribute that include additional app settings, but my changes are not only app setting.

Comment: You just have to make it part of your deployment process. You *should* be using an automated deployment process. VSTS, TFS, Octopus deploy, custom scripts, something like that. If you're manually deploying applications, you're doing it wrong.

Comment: @mason yes, I'm fine with making it automatic. But does it mean I have to write a script to merge the config file or is there a tool doing that?

Comment: It will depend on what you use to do your deployment

Comment: @mason I know nothing about the deployment tools. I just pick randomly, say, VSTS.

Comment: Yes, VSTS has release tasks you can use to modify the configuration for specific environments. You can do token replacement, or web deploy, or custom scripts etc.